# jquery passing variable like regular expression to an id selector

Tags: jquery, regex

I catch the `onclick` event on a `<div>` to show or hide some table row on the base of the id they have. So I do the following

```
function showTable(name){
    var temp = $(name).attr('id');
    var r = new RegExp(temp);
    $('[id^="' + r + '"]').each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('row-shown')
    });
}
```

This work if I change the `r` Regular Expression with a word, but due to the dynamic creation of the tables and the infinite possibility of ID values, I cannot have a static behavior.

What can I do to let it work?

Comment: I don't see any indication in the [jquery ^= page](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that it supports using a RegExp. Why can't you just say `$('[id^="' + temp + '"]')`

Comment: The question needs clarification. What is the RegExp for? If the ID of the 'name' object is the same as the id you're looking for (which shouldn't really happen in the DOM, unless they ARE the same object), you could replace the the contents of your function with: $('#' + $(name).attr('id')).toggleClass('row-shown');

Comment: It's not the same it starts with 'temp' (id^=)